# Invoke C/C++ code from C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I usually use C# but have the pleasure to invoke a C method via C++. So I wrote a C++ wrapper like this:

The C++ header file looks like this:

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace CSharpToCPP {

    public ref class SomeWrapper
    {
        public:
        double ReturnValue();
    };
}
```

The C++ code looks like this:

```
double CSharpToCPP::SomeWrapper::ReturnValue()
{
    return 1;
}
```

This gives me dll which I can reference in C#. The working code in C# looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeWrapper Wrapper = new SomeWrapper();

        Console.WriteLine(Wrapper.ReturnValue());
    }
}
```

Now I would like to create some data in the C++ method ReturnValue and invoke the C method with this signature:

```
real_T get_value(const e_struct_T parameters, real_T temp)
```

Can someone please be so kind and point me in the right direction which explains what a const e_struct_T is and how to create such data? The C code was automatically generated and should take a structure  with known content. I tried to define a structure in the header file like this:

```
struct Parameters{
    double x;
    int y;
    char z1;
    bool z2;
};
```

and then populate it with data like this:

```
Parameters Ps;
Ps.x = z2;
Ps.x = 2.0;
```

before invoking get_value like this:

```
get_value(Ps, 10.0);
```

This does not work. Thanks!

Comment: You would save lot of hassle if you use C++/CLI wrapper for your C++ class

Comment: He is. (Actually it would probably be easier to use P/Invoke for a simple call like this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must search for an header file containing the definition of `e_struct_t`, include in the calling file, and use a variable of that type to pass to `get_value`;
By the way, if the target method you want to call from `C#` is pure `C`, you probably should consider better using `P/Invoke` ( [a tutorial here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx) ) directly instead of create a C++ wrapper. Furthermore by plain P/Invoke you will drastically simplify the deploy ( no additional dll needed )

Comment: I just figured this out myself (-:. Can you please be so kind and provide a reference to P/Invoke? Thanks.

Comment: @csetzkorn there is a starting point link in the answer. I *know* it may be a little frustating having such tings working, so don't get discouraged.